# Semver library is giving me an invalid version for 0.0.001

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I have this piece of code:

```
  const semver = require('semver');

  let oldestVersion = '0.0.001';
  let youngestVersion = '9999.99.999';
  let youngestPackageName = null;
  let oldestPackageName = null;

  Object.keys(confirmProjects).forEach(k => {
    const v = confirmProjects[k];

    if (semver.lte(v.localVersion, youngestVersion)) {  // fails here
      youngestVersion = v.localVersion;
      youngestPackageName = v.name;
    }

    if (semver.gte(v.localVersion, oldestVersion)) {
      oldestVersion = v.localVersion;
      oldestPackageName = v.name;
    }
  });
```

the error is:

> ```
> TypeError: Invalid Version: 0.0.001
>     at new SemVer (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/npp/node_modules/semver/semver.js:305:11)
>     at compare (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/npp/node_modules/semver/semver.js:578:39)
>     at Function.gte (/home/oleg/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/npp/node_modules/semver/semver.js:627:10)
> ```

Does anyone know how to mitigate this or what might be wrong with my cdoe?

Comment: You should have read the [SemVer spec](https://semver.org) before posting this. Leading zeros have been banned from all numeric fields since version 2.0.0, at least several years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is invalid.  It should be `0.0.1` instead.

If you need three digits for your revision, you can use them later... after `0.0.9` comes `0.0.10`.  After `0.0.99` comes `0.0.100`, etc.